# Where goes original asteroids mass after impact?

Tags: asteroids, impact, crater

In relation to possible asteroid mining on the moon, where goes asteroid mass after the impact? Will it be burried, scathered, or evaporated?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Huge points for the drawings here.

Comment: Correct answer is  "yes"   :-) , or   "D all of the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three.  The impact velocity will be huge and the kinetic energy of astroid extremely large. The asteroid will be pulverized into millions of fragments of asteroid. Many of these will be as small as dust particles and will be vaporized from the heat associated with collision. Hence some small fragments will evaporate will other larger fragments will be buried or blown away from impact site. The scatter field is an ellipse about the crater elongated along direction of motion of meteor.